# Custom Assetic Filter

Tags: symfony, assetic

Is any posibilities to include service file with assetic filter definition as YML file in config.yml? Assetic expects XML structure...

bundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
    assetic.filter.csslint:
    class: IOKI\CommonBundle\Assetic\Filter\CssLintFilter
    tags:
        - { name: assetic.filter, alias: csslint}
```

config.yml

```
assetic:
    filters:
        csslint:
            resource: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Project/CommonBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The discussion in [a related issue](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/50) against Assetic implies that you can point your `resource` key at an arbitrary XML file (the examples there use `'assetic.xml'` and then it will be okay specifying your filter in `services.yml` as normal.

(I found that this only worked if I cleared my Symfony cache and did a "hard-refresh" in my browser - it wasn't until I tried that that this actually worked for me.)

Furthermore, if you only want to reference your filter directly from a template rather than in `config.yml`, you don't need to mention it in `config.yml` at all.  You can just specify your filter in `services.yml` as you've done, and reference it in Twig.  E.g:

```
{% stylesheets
   'bundles/boardworksapp/less/custom.less' filter='csslint'
%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```